# Object reference not set to an instance of an object (noob)

Tags: list, constructor, initializing

I have this simple code, but I get the error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" when I try to access the "MyCarslist" initialized in my constructor. What am I missing?

```
 class Cars
{
    public List<Car> MyCarslist { get; set; }


    public void AddCar(Car car)
    {
      MyCarslist.Add(car);
      Console.WriteLine(MyCarslist.Count);
    }

    public Cars()
    {
    List<Car> MyCarslist = new List<Car>();
    }
```

Both `Mycarslist.add(car);` and `Console.WriteLine(MyCarslist.Count);` give the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are declaring a variable with this line

List MyCarslist = new List();

not setting the property. Try this..

MyCarslist = new List();

Thanks,
O

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
public Cars()
{
    List<Car> MyCarslist = new List<Car>();
}
```

to this:

```
public Cars()
{
    this.MyCarslist = new List<Car>();
}
```